# Number and different kinds of spnning trees in a weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, entropy, network-theory

We know that for a unweighted graph the number $\tau(\mathcal{G})$ of unique spanning trees of $\mathcal{G}$ is $$\tau(\mathcal{G})=\det L_\mathcal{G}^{\{n-1\}},$$ where $L_\mathcal{G}^{\{n-1\}}$ is constructed by removing an arbitrary $i$th row and column of graph Laplacian $L_\mathcal{G}$.

Now, I am concerned the **weighted graph**.

For example, consider complete graph $n=3$ with weights $e_1 = w_1$, $e_2 = w_2$, $e_3 = w_3$. We know $$\det(L_g^{n-1} ) = w_1w_2+w_1w_3+w_2w_3.$$ And actually, we have these three kinds of spanning tree. (and it also tells us what kind of spanning tree.)

For example, consider tree graph $n=3$, i.e., $1-2-3$ with weight $e_1 = w_1$, $e_2 = w_2$. We know $$\det(L_g^{n-1} ) = w_1w_2.$$ And of course, we only have one spanning tree.

So conclusion from these examples:

1. number of terms $=$ number of spanning trees
2. each term tells the type of spanning tree

> My question is that are both conclusions general for any **connected**, **weighted**, **undirected** and **no self-loop** graph?

Any related papers are also welcome. I know $\tau(\mathcal{G})$ is related to **loop entropy** of $\mathcal{G}$ from a few papers; however, I have not seen the version for weighted graphs. So also hope for related papers if they are closely related to my problems.

Thanks!

Comment: This related question should help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10493/the-matrix-tree-theorem-for-weighted-graphs