# Using matrix tree theorem on enlarged graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

[The matrix tree theorem for weighted graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10493/the-matrix-tree-theorem-for-weighted-graphs)

Seeing this question left me wondering, is it possible to modify the matrix so one can compute the following sum:
$$
P'(G) = \sum_{T\subseteq G}{m'(T)}
$$
where
$m'(T) = \prod_{e \in (E-T)}{\omega_e}$. Is this possible?

Comment: We have $P'(G) = (\prod_{e\in E}\omega_e)^{\#T} P(G)\mid_{\omega_e \to \omega_e^{-1}}$, so your $P'(G)$ is very easy to obtain from $P(G)$.